# How to demonstrate your data analysis in python such as dashboard

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, dashboard

I am doing a data analysis by using python. However, I still didn't find answer to this question. After completing the work how I can send it to colleagues or boss who are not using python.
For example if I did the analysis in excel (pivots) they can browse the analysis easily using the slicers.
But in python is there any way that can make dashboard for the results so they can select the case of analysis and it will show up. and does that require them to download any type of software?

Thanks for your help

Just wondering if anyway to use python with people who are not using it

Comment: i have voted to close as this is opinion based.

Comment: @D.L How is `is there any way that can make dashboard for the results so they can select the case of analysis and it will show up. and does that require them to download any type of software?` opinion based? This is a specific question asking if a feature exists.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plotly.express is a good option. You can build dashboards and save them as html. They are interactive, so all your colleagues need to do is open them and interact.

Here are some examples:
https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/

it's a library and will need to be installed.
Use `pip install plotly-express`

Hope it helps. :)